# Camara para tomar foto en android

Tags: javascript, android, html

Tengo un codigo funcional en donde puedo tomar una foto desde la pc jalando el archivo desde localhost, pueden probarlo para ver su funcionalidad, el problema es cuando paso el codigo a mi movil y ya no funciona, no se si deba descargar algun plugin o compilarlo en algun lugar para que pueda ser compatible con dispositivos android

```js
(function () {
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    canvas = document.getElementById ('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext ('2d'),
    photo = document.getElementById('photo'),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia;

        navigator.getMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: false
        }, function (stream){
            video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
            //
        },  function(error){
            //An error occured
            //error.code

        });

        document.getElementById('capture').addEventListener('click', function(){
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
                photo.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
        });

})();
```

```css
.booth{
    width:400px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    border:10px solid #ddd;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.booth-capture-button{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none; 

}

#canvas {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

    <body>
        <div class="booth">
            <video id="video" width="400" height="300"></video>
            <a href="#" id="capture" class="booth-capture-button">Tomar foto</a>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
            <img id='photo' src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300" alt="Foto tuya">
        </div>
        <script src="js/photo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: No, tuve que cambiarlo a un upload de fotos normal, estaba contra tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizar esto

```
<img id="photo" class="photo">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="camera" />
```

y luego para mostrar la foto con JavaScript

```
  const photo = document.querySelector('#photo');
  const camera = document.querySelector('#camera');
  camera.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    photo.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  });
```

Te recomiendo convertir el sitio web en una PWA, que se puede hacer de forma sencilla

Comment: Revisar [answer]